# Diretório e extensão de arquivo FileStream

Tags: c#

Como especificar o diretório de criação do arquivo e a sua extensão?

```
byte[] vetorImagem = (byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
string strNomeArquivo = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
FileStream fs = new FileStream(strNomeArquivo, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
fs.Write(vetorImagem, 0, vetorImagem.Length);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
pbDefault.Visible = false;
pbUsuario.Image = Image.FromFile(strNomeArquivo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade o que você passa como primeiro parâmetro no [construtor do `FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft(v=vs.110).aspx) não é o nome do arquivo, mas o *endereço* (*path*) do arquivo.

O endereço dele deve conter o caminho, nome e extensão do arquivo em uma só *string*.
Portanto após obter o nome do arquivo você deveria concatenar o resto das informações para ter o endereço completo:

```
string strNomeArquivo = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()),
localizacaoArquivo = "c:/",
extensaoArquivo = ".png",
enderecoArquivo = localizacaoArquivo + strNomeArquivo + extensaoArquivo;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(enderecoArquivo, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
...
```

Note que se você quiser o caminho de alguma pasta padrão do Windows, você pode obtê-las usando o *Enum* de [pastas especiais do sistema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx).
Para a pasta *Minhas Imagens* do usuário, por exemplo:

```
string localizacaoArquivo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
```

Comment: o meu sistema criou o arquivo no diretório padrão com nome ex: Cache131113874626944091 e não executou a ação esperada

Comment: `string strNomeArquivo = Convert.ToString("Cache\\" + txtUsuario.Text + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".ebtemp"),
                extensaoArquivo = "",
                enderecoArquivo = strNomeArquivo + extensaoArquivo;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(enderecoArquivo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                fs.Write(vetorImagem, 0, vetorImagem.Length);
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
                pbDefault.Visible = false;
                pbUsuario.Image = Image.FromFile(strNomeArquivo);`

Modifiquei e deu certo!